# Why usb with root filesystem is not mounting on boot bootcode.bin not working

Tags: usb, pi-zero, boot-issues, pi-b+, root

Hi I am making this thread because someone pointed that my previous was not specific enough.
I am trying to move my root filesystem to external usb on my raspberry zero v1.3. I have additional raspberry pi 1B+ which I use for debugging cause it has regular hdmi output. I followed a few tutorials on how to do it an here are the steps i took:

Creating PRIAMRY partition via fstab on dev/sda called dev/sda1, then i formated the partition":
`sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -L my_data /dev/sda1`

Next step was mounting the partition in /mnt folder and copying root files to /dev/sda1
`sudo rsync -axv / /mnt`

The last thing I was supposed to do was changing cmdline.txt so that root=PARTUUID coresponds to the PARTUUID of dev/sda1 and at the end of the file I added rootdelay. And just before the reboot i changed /etc/fstab so that now it should mount my partition at boot now it says:

`PARTUUID=My dev/sda1 UUID            /       ext4    noatime,nodiratime,defaults     0 1`

And still no luck. After the reboot it says "waiting for root device PARTUUID=******************".

This is my /etc/fstab:
`proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0 PARTUUID=39c0b0b1-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2 PARTUUID=735ad48f-8226-cd40-8405-77d27761a4e7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1`

This is my /boot/cmdline.txt:
`console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=735ad48f-8226-cd40-8405-77d27761a4e7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_ether rootdelay=5`

I was trying different configurations like root=dev/sda1 in both cmdline.txt and fstab files.
I tried using several more usb drives, like SSD or HDD even few pendrives. Still no luck. It acts like root is not mounting. I thought it was because of raspberry undervoltage so i bought external power supply for my hdd disk. Nothing changed.

Then I came across this usb_boot [script](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=196778). It moves all of the files from sd to usb, and changes cmdline.txt so that it points to root on usb. According to the creator and official raspberry pi website all i need after moving boot and root partitions to usb is sd card formated to fat32 and bootcode.bin file on it. But when I insert sd card to raspberry zero or b+ with only bootcode.bin it acts like there is no sd card at all. It just dont boot no matter what. All I need is move root to usb because it is going to be read/write server and i need higher capacity and durability. Why the bootcode.bin does not work and why usb drive is not mounting on boot when I use boot from sd and root on usb? Please help it is getting really frustrating I have been trying to fix this for weeks.

Comment: `PARTUUID=735ad48f-8226-cd40-8405-77d27761a4e7` isn't a valid PARTUUID ... root will likely be `PARTUUID=39c0b0b1-02` - or use `UUID=735ad48f-8226-cd40-8405-77d27761a4e7` since that's the UUID of the root partition, not the PARTUUID

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your Question, much detail missing.

There are 2 fundamental issues:-

1. 735ad48f-8226-cd40-8405-77d27761a4e7 is **NOT** a PARTUUID
2. `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` is incompatible with use of the USB for storage.

Frankly trying to use a Pi Zero with an external drive is a waste of time. You would be better to get a real Pi.

If you **REALLY** want to try boot the Pi, then use `SD Card Copier` to copy to the HDD, selecting the option to create a new PARTUUID, then edit `cmdline.txt` on the SD Card to use the PARTUUID of the copied HDD.